# Compilation is successful but getting bytecode = "0x"

Tags: hardhat, solc, compilation, compiler, zksync

I am trying to compile this very simple smart contract but I am getting its `bytecode = "0x"`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyERC20 is ERC20 {
    uint8 private _decimals;

    constructor(
        string memory name_,
        string memory symbol_,
        uint8 decimals_
    ) ERC20(name_, symbol_) {
        _decimals = decimals_;
    }

    function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) public returns (bool) {
        _mint(_to, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function decimals() public view override returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }
}
```

This is my `hardhat.config.ts` file:

```
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy";
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc";
const { pk } = require('./.secrets.json');

module.exports = {
  zksolc: {
    version: "1.3.1",
    compilerSource: "binary",
    settings: {},
  },
  defaultNetwork: "zkSyncTestnet",
  networks: {
    zkSyncTestnet: {
      url: "https://zksync2-testnet.zksync.dev",
      ethNetwork: "goerli", // Can also be the RPC URL of the network (e.g. `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<API_KEY>`)
      zksync: true,
      accounts: [pk]
    },
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.17",
  },
};
```

As you may see, I am using `hardhat` with `@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc`.

Comment: As of today, `zkSync` devs are still looking into this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest is 1.3.8 and should solve the issues you are running into. Here is our changelog for how to update your project https://era.zksync.io/docs/dev/troubleshooting/changelog.html#compilers-and-plugins-apr-4th-2023